# Laravel api backend session management with SPA frontend. Session expires when redirected

Tags: php, laravel, session, csrf

I have implemented a laravel API backend application and integrated a SPA frontend with next js.

I have configured my local development environment to hostnames as -

`api.mysite.local` -> Laravel backend 
`mysite.local` -> Front end with next js

Everything works just fine except in this situation.

I have implemented a payment gateway. Which needs a callback url in my application to upadate the transaction information.
As per the requirement I have the callback set to

`http://api.mysite.local/payment/success`

Now As I handle the post request successfully sent to the given endpoint from the payment gateway, I then redirect the user back to my SPA url 
`http://mysite.local/?trn="suitable_transaction_id"`

using the Code:

```
class MyController extends Controller{
  public function success(Request $request){
     //My request handler code 

     return redirect()->to(env('SPA_URL') . '/?trn=' . json_encode($tran_id));
     
  }
}
```

The route `/payment/success` is included in `web.php` 
All other routes that uses the backend service are situated in `api.php` of the routes folder in Laravel.

But the problem arises here is that the session gets expired and the user then needs to login again after the redirection to my SPA.

the .env file in my laravel application is as such-

```
APP_URL=http://api.mysite.local
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120
SESSION_DOMAIN=.mysite.local
SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS=mysite.local,.mysite.local
SPA_URL=http://mysite.local
```

I have used sanctum to handle SPA authorization and as per the gateways requirement I have excluded the
`http://api.mysite.local/payment/success`
from csrf token check.

So how may I prevent the session expiry from occurring and what changes do I make to the .env file  in order for my session management and cors to work properly.

Comment: I haven't used the SPA logic yet in Laravel, but looking at your problem, it occurs to me two solutions: 1) increment the SESSION_LIFETIME value in your .env, lets say 30 days = 43200. 2) Pass an argument to SPA_URL, like a token, read the token and authenticate the user if necessary.

Comment: What I have understood so far is as I am redirected to an external url outside my domain and again I am redirected back to my backend url and then front-end url respectively, the session is automatically invalidated. I am confused to an extent that should I use laravels session management with database as I am currently using file based session management? which in fact leads somewhat to your second solution.

Comment: The redirection shouldn't be a problem, otherwise, what happens if your user comes back to your app after a day or two? Isn't he logged in, through `remember_me` token? Does he always have to login?

Comment: No, if I put remember_me the session is still destroyed after a few hours. i.e after 120 minutes. As I have mentioned in my question, after I have redirected to the payment gateways url, it sends a post request to - api.mysite.local/payment/success. The controller then redirects back to the SPA url, the session is then destroyed and I have to login again. Even if I don't redirect back to the SPA from the controller the session is still destroyed and I need to login again.

Comment: If you're using the `remember_me` option and you are logout of the app after closing the browser or being away for 30 minutes, you should forget about the redirect and figure out why that happens. Btw, the `SESSION_LIFETIME` is in seconds and not in minutes, so when you say `120 minutes`, I hope it was a lapse.

Comment: Thanks. The remember_me option works now, there was a problem in my login handler not sending the remember in the payload I have fixed it and it works now. That is with the remember_me enabled the user is not logged out after the redirection from the payment gateway url., but without the remember_me the user is logged out. What can be the cause of this?  The SESSION_LIFETIME as mentioned in the session.php file is in minutes an by default it was set to 120. How may I solve the issue?

Comment: The principle should be the same, the redirection, unless you're doing something in between, shouldn't logout your user. Like in the following scenario » user goes to your website » log in » browses your website » decides to leave by their own will » comes back after 10 minutes » its still logged in, even without remember me option. Try the following, in your JS, redirect to `window.location.href = 'https://google.com'` and then hit the back button in your browser / type your website url...and see if you're still logged in.